# Is the countdown timer browser dependent?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, timer

I have used a jQuery countdown timer in a website. But what I observed is that, it shows different time on different browsers, like the timer shown on chrome/ firefox differs with that shown on IE.

And when I tried changing my machine time, to my wonder the timer was also changing according to it.

So, my first query is, whether the countdown timer is browser specific?
And the second, does this timer refer to machine time and not the server time on which the website is hosted?

Comment: "The" countdown timer, "which" countdown timer is that?  Without the code this question is not answerable.

Comment: Actually I'm using Drupal module and I have asked related to Drupal on the respective community. But I want to know in general. When I went through few sites showing jQuery timer demo (like this: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) it was showing machine dependent timer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the plugin is implemented. Mostly it can be both, probably whichever you like. You have to read the specific documentation for the plugin that you want to use. In the examples, it can either show the time that is pushed from the backend (server time) or show your local machine/browser time (accessible through JavaScript in the browser with `new Date();`).

By the way, [jQuery Countdown](http://%20keith-wood.name/countdown.html) shows the same time inside every browser for me.

Comment: I think there must be some problem in my site as it is showing different time on different browsers.

Yes, it showed same time to me as well. But most of the demo timers change when you change your system time. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I tried few sites from following site: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-countdown-timer-plugin/ showing demo timer and it was changing when I changed my machine time.